# Putting MinGW under configuration management

Tags: version-control, mingw

I have an application that gets built under MinGW. I have my source code under Git, but I ought to have my build environment under proper configuration management too, so that if I need to repeat a build from 6 months ago I can do it with the same versions of the compiler, libraries etc.

Is there any way of doing this? I've read up on "repeatable" builds, but that seems to be about running the build twice with the same versions of everything and getting a bitwise identical output, which is necessary for certain security properties. My problem is how to restore the version of MinGW files that I had at some point in the past.

The crude and primitive way would be to just archive a snapshot of C:\mingw every time I use pacman. But I'm hoping for something a bit smarter.

Answer (score 0):

The standalone builds of MinGW-w64 from http://winlibs.com/, which can build for both Windows 32-bit and 64-bit, have no installation procedure. Just extract the download and you have a working build environment.

This even allows you to even have multiple versions of MinGW-w64 side by side.

Just make sure no other installed MinGW (like the one in `C:\mingw`) is in your PATH so the different versions don't get accidentally mixed up.

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is actually the GTK libraries plus a few other things.